# Мультифильтер, который не работает по 1 стобику

Tags: javascript, php, html

Существует JS фильтр

```
   <script>
$("select.fliter").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.fliter").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("label").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("label." + filters).css('display', 'block');
});
</script>

<select name="metal-type" id="metal-type" class="js-select fliter">
                             <option value="1">- Выберите тип металла -</option>
                            <option value="Платина">Платина</option>
                            <option value="Золото">Золото</option>
                            <option value="Серебро">Серебро</option>
                        </select>

<select name="metal-try" id="metal-try" class="js-select fliter">
                        <option value="1">- Выберите пробу -</option>                                                               <?
                            $arResult = Array();
                            $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME","PROBA", "OCENKA_SKUPKA"); 
                            $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 6, "SECTION_ID"=>1364,"ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"); 
                            $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>21), $arSelect); 
                            while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) { 
                                $arFields = $ob->GetFields(); 
                                $idof = $arFields['ID'];
                            $resULT = CIBlockElement::GetByID($idof);
                            $resULT1 = $resULT->GetNextElement();
                            $resULT2 = $resULT1->GetProperties(); 
                            $resULT3 = $resULT1->GetFields();
                            //print_r($resULT2['PROBA']['VALUE']);
                            echo '<option class="filt '; echo $resULT2['TIP_MATER']['VALUE']; echo'" value="'; echo $resULT2['PROBA']['VALUE']; echo'">'; /*echo $resULT2['TIP_MATER']['VALUE'];*/ echo $resULT2['PROBA']['VALUE'];echo'</option>';
                            /*if($resULT2['TIP_MATER']['VALUE'] == 'Золото'){
                                echo '<option value="'; echo $resULT2['PROBA']['VALUE']; echo'">'; echo $resULT2['PROBA']['VALUE']; echo'</option>';
                            }*/
                        }

  echo '<div id="FilterContainer"> <label style="display:none;" class="';                             $arResultS = Array();
                        $arSelectS = Array("ID", "NAME","PROBA", "TIP_MATER"); 
                        $arFilterS = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 6, "SECTION_ID"=>$resULT2['USLOV_OCENKI']['VALUE'], "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"); 
                        $resS = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilterS, false, Array("nPageSize"=>21), $arSelectS); 
                        while($obS = $resS->GetNextElement()) { 
                            $arFieldsS = $obS->GetFields(); 
                            $idofS = $arFieldsS['ID'];
                        $resULTS = CIBlockElement::GetByID($idofS);
                        $resULT1S = $resULTS->GetNextElement();
                        $resULT2S = $resULT1S->GetProperties(); 
                        $resULT3S = $resULT1S->GetFields();
                        echo $resULT2S['TIP_MATER']['VALUE']." "; echo $resULT2S['PROBA']['VALUE']." "; 
                        
                    }echo '">'; echo '<div class="ea__card" data-category="'; if($resULT2S['OCENKA_ZALOG']['VALUE'] != '')
                    {
                        echo "Залог";
                    }else{
                        echo "Скупка";
                    } echo'">';
```

Не получается сделать, чтобы по одному фильтру не показывало, а именно в связке при выборе двух только отображало блок. Подскажите что забыл указать?

Comment: Думаю нужно добавить больше кода и разметки

Comment: @AzizUmarov Добавил

Answer (score 0):

Насколько можно разобраться в вашей простыне, управление видимостью осуществляется выбором соответствующего класса? Тогда нужный элемент будет показан только при совпадении двух классов, т.е. при выборе двух селектов, доп. проверки не нужны.
Почему же у вас не работает? Классы  с точками в имени не лучшее решение. Используйте вместо точки нижний подчерк (там где join) и элементам присваивайте классы соответственно gold_585 или silver_875 и т.д.:

```
$("select.fliter").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.fliter").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join("_");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("label").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("label." + filters).css('display', 'block');
});
```

http://www.jooom.ru/toster/jq1.php